# Replacement for Turbo Pascal (3.0)

Tags: windows-7, pascal

I have a family member who is dearly attached to this antiquated pascal implementation by Borland.

He recently purchased a new laptop with windows 7 (64 bit), and I was able to help him get his old Turbo Pascal environment up through DOSBox, but this is less than ideal.  It's slow, and a bit esoteric.

He does recognize that this environment is a thing of the past, but he's comfortable with it and doesn't want to change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/down/x86_64/win64.var).... Works fine for me ;]

Mike.

Comment: The (TP clone) textmode IDE only works properly with 64-bit in the mainbranch. Suggest to use the 32-bit version instead

Comment: The FreePascal IDE is almost a direct feature-for-feature copy of TurboPascal's DOS ide.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) which is Turbo Pascal compatible, free and even has a selection of IDEs available for it, [Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/) (no relation) being one.

Comment: Lazarus looks a lot like Delphi 1-Delphi 7, but not like Turbo Pascal's DOS Ide.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi

Comment: This is of course, the modern way to go, and is the way I would recommend, even though a lot of learning and adaptation would be required.  However I doubt that it's what the question is asking for.  The question is asking for the "most DOS TurboPascal like" alternative. If this guy hasn't learned Delphi and it's been over 15 years since Delphi 1.0 shipped, I doubt he's moving ever.